# Как вывести элементы многомерного массива, начинающиеся на букву "К"

Tags: php

Есть данный массив:

```
$aCities = array(
    "Московская область" => array("Москва", "Зеленоград", "Клин"),
    "Ленинградская область" => array("Санкт-Петербург", "Всеволожск", "Павловск", "Кронштадт"),
    "Рязанская область" => array("Рязань", "Касимов", "Ряжск")
);

foreach ($aCities as $sKey => $aCity) { 
    echo("$sKey:" . "\n\r");      
    foreach ($aCity as $sCity) {         
        echo($sCity . " ");     
    }
echo "\n\r";
}
```

Как мне вывести города, начинающиеся на букву К?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте array_walk_recursive() и mb_substr():

```
array_walk_recursive($aCities, function($item, $key){
    mb_substr($item, 0, 1) != 'К' ?: print "$item<br>";
});
```

Результат:

```
Клин
Кронштадт
Касимов
```

---

Если нужно решение именно посредством циклов, тогда так:

```
foreach ($aCities as $aCity) { 
    foreach ($aCity as $sCity) { 
        mb_substr($sCity, 0, 1) != 'К' ?: print "$sCity<br>";
    }
}
```